# Why are they called the "gang of four"?

Tags: design-patterns

The writers of the Dragon book are called gof. Why is that?

Are they some kind of clique that always hangs out together?

Comment: I don't think you mean the Dragon book. The gang is some silly C++ cult.

Comment: I have never heard Aho, Sethi and Ullman called the "gang of four", but they are almost exactly the right number.

Comment: @Richard As a bears fan, I think this is the first time we've ever been in agreement :)

Comment: @Richard Pennington: Sorry. Grammar-Grump here. It's a French name, FaVRe, even if Brett himself says "farv".

Answer (score 22):

GoF refers to the authors of "Design Patterns" Gamma, Helm, Johnson and Vlissides. There was four of them. It's a parody relating to Mao's [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four).

Comment: Nice link. Thanks. I thought it was silly C++ stuff.